# RSpec, checking that an instance received a method & argument

Tags: ruby, oop, rspec, mocking

I have a class as follows...

```
     class Sequencer

            def initialize(error_raiser: nil)
            @error_raiser = error_raiser || ErrorRaiser.new
            end

            def order(string)
            error_raiser.raise_error(string)
            end

            attr_reader :error_raiser

            end
```

How might I check in my sequencer_spec file that @error_raiser received raise_error with a string? I have tried using an instance spy like so...

```
  let(:error_raiser) { instance_spy("ErrorRaiser" }
  describe Sequencer do
    describe '.order' do
      it "passes the string to an error_raiser" do
        subject.order("a => b,")
        expect(error_raiser).to have_received(:raise_error).with("a => b")
      end
    end
  end
```

However i get the following error...

```
 (InstanceDouble(ErrorRaiser) (anonymous)).raise_error("a => b")
 expected: 1 time with arguments: ("a => b")
 received: 0 times
```

Comment: Is the extra comma in the call to subject.order intentional?

Answer (score 0):

You should tell rspec that you replace its error_raiser with the one defined in the `let`.

```
subject.stub(:error_raiser).and_return(error_raiser)
```

(Depending on rspec version) Usually it is not necessary to do an instance spy. The following should work

```
describe '.order' do
    it "passes the string to an error_raiser" do
        expect(subject.error_raiser).to receive(:raise_error).with("a => b")
        subject.order("a => b")
    end
end
```